# What is the complex-envelope notation?

Tags: demodulation

In reading a paper on demodulation there was this sentence:

> "Using complex-envelope notation, the noise corrupted waveform at the
>   IF filter output can be written as...".

I've not heard this term, what does the complex-envelope notation mean?

The equation below that statement is:

$$z(t) =  \mathrm{Re} \left\{ \widetilde{z}(t)e^{j2\pi f_0t+\theta} \right\}$$

Comment: Read about [**analytic signal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal) and this [**presentation**](http://ocw.korea.edu/ocw/college-of-engineering/d1b5c2e0c774b860/lecturenote19may19.pdf) will become clear.

Comment: The z on the right side of the equation had a tilda over it, I'm not sure how to represent that here though.